# Install PyYAML on linux (centos 7) to for Python3.3

Tags: python, centos7, pyyaml

I currently have python2.6 and python3.3 on this machine with CentOS 7. I installed PyYAML by using "yum install PyYAML", but I can only import yaml in python2.6, not working in python3.3. Any idea how to fix this? I want to be able to use PyYAML in python3.3 on CentOS 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just install it using pip:

```
pip3 install PyYAML
```

Comment: I dont have pip installed yet...when I try yum search pip, it doesn't give me any valid option. Any thought on that? Thanks!

Comment: You could install it manually using [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), as described in [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html).

Comment: Okay...the problem now is whenever I try to python3 get-pip.py", I get "zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available". So I "yum -y install zlib*", but again this installed everything to python2.6, and I can only do "python get-pip.py"...How can I fix this?

Comment: Was python 3 already installed on this system or did you have to use some extra repository like [described here](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/install-python-3-in-centos-7/)? Anyway try to run: "easy_install pip".

Comment: python2.6 was installed on this system and I manually installed python3.3...I did "easy_install pip", and it was installed successfully. I then tried "pip3 install PyYAML", it said "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyYAML in /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages"... What should I do now? Thanks...

Comment: I only have `pip`, `pip2` and `pip2.7` which are all for python 2. What is the proper way to install an additional pip's for python 3 since I allow my cPanel customers to choose which version of python to use, 2 or 3. I'm using CloudLinux as well.